# How to show default value of mui v5 select component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to be able to show the default value if nothing is selected yet for the following mui v5 select component the issue is it is empty...

```js
   <StyledCustomDataSelect
        variant='outlined'
        labelId='demo-simple-select-standard-label'
        id='demo-simple-select-standard'
        name='selectCustomData'
        disabled={customEquipment?.length === 0}
        value={selected.customEquipment}
        onChange={handleSelect}
        sx={{ width: 300, textAlign: 'start', margin: '10px' }}
      >
        <MyListSubheader>Custom Equipment</MyListSubheader>
        {customData?.map((el, index) => el.type === 'customEquipment' && <MenuItem value={el.name}>             {el.name}</MenuItem>)} 
    </StyledCustomDataSelect>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show a default value in the Select component when nothing is selected yet by adding an additional `<MenuItem>` element with the default value and an empty value attribute. See the updated version of your code below;

```
<StyledCustomDataSelect
  variant="outlined"
  labelId="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
  id="demo-simple-select-standard"
  name="selectCustomData"
  disabled={customEquipment?.length === 0}
  value={selected.customEquipment}
  onChange={handleSelect}
  sx={{ width: 300, textAlign: "start", margin: "10px" }}
>
  <MyListSubheader>Custom Equipment</MyListSubheader>
  // Default select value
  <MenuItem value="">Select an option</MenuItem>
  {customData?.map(
    (el, index) =>
      el.type === "customEquipment" && (
        <MenuItem key={index} value={el.name}>
          {el.name}
        </MenuItem>
      )
  )}
</StyledCustomDataSelect>
```

In the code above, I have added the `<MenuItem>` with an empty value attribute that serves as the default value. Hope this helps.

Comment: can I some how hide it in the drop down without any extra rerenders.. hidden is not working on it.